# PowerShell Replacing text in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

I am building a script to pull information from one system and place it into a CSV for another system to pull it. I have to do some data cleanup before that though. I am pulling userid's from the system and they come out as dom\userid. For my other system to use it i have to have just the userid with no dom. I used the below code to remove dom and this works:

```
    $csv = Import-Csv C:\Support\Broker.csv
$csv | %{ If ($_.LastConnectionUser -like "*DOM*") { $_.LastConnectionUser -replace 'DOM', '' } }
$csv | Export-Csv C:\Support\Broker.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

This leaves me with \userid. As soon as I add the \ to the replace string, the system freaks because it tries to interpret the \ and can't do a  replace so I tried the following

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Support\Broker.csv
    $csv | %{ If ($_.LastConnectionUser -like "*DOM*") { $_.LastConnectionUser -replace 'DOM`\', '' } }
    $csv | Export-Csv C:\Support\Broker.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

I get the same error

> ERROR: Regular expression pattern is not valid: DOM_WFLD`\.
>   broker.ps1 (24): ERROR: At Line: 24 char: 54
>   ERROR: + $csv | %{ If ($_.LastConnectionUser -like "*DOM*") { $_.LastConnectionUser -repl ...
>   ERROR: +                                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ERROR:     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (DOM_WFLD`:String) [], RuntimeException
>   ERROR:     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidRegularExpression

I can't seem to get this to work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

On the line that contains `$csv | %{ If ($_.LastConnectionUser -like "*DOM*") { $_.LastConnectionUser -replace 'DOM`\', '' } }`

It could be simplified and made more versitale.

`$csv | %{ $_.LastConnectionUser -replace '\w+\\'}`

If statement for something like this is not really required since the action you are taking doesnt significantly increase processing time. Also your IF will match if a user name contains `DOM` which i imagine was not your intention.

Which would replace all characters infront of a `\` including the `\` itself. As David explains you need to escape the `\` as it is a special chracter in regular expressions. `-replace` with no second parameter automatically just removes the match.

Answer (score 0):

```
$csv = Import-Csv C:\Support\Broker.csv
    $csv | %{ If ($_.LastConnectionUser -like "*DOM*") { $_.LastConnectionUser -replace 'DOM\\', '' } }
    $csv | Export-Csv C:\Support\Broker.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

The escape you have to use is the *regular expression* one (so backslash), not the PowerShell one (back tick)